# Use keyboard instead of mouse click with calculator - created using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a calculator with JavaScript.

I want to make sure that when I press a key on my keyboard it appears in the textbox without clicking on the textbox. So basically, I don't only want you to click on the calculator buttons with your mouse, but also using the keys. But how do I make sure of this? Please advise.

Following is the code:

```
<script>

    // toon values die aangeklikt worden in de 'uitkomst' input.
    function nmr(val){
        document.getElementById('uitkomst').value+=val;
    }

    function reken(){
    // ALS er op de = teken is geklikt >>
    // ik maak een variabele aan dat de "uitkomst" values ophaalt
        var value1= document.getElementById('uitkomst').value;
        // ik maak een variabele aan dat vervolgens met 'eval' de value execute. 
        // 'eval' is het evalueren of het executen van een string.
        var res = eval(value1);
        // toon/vul vervolgens bij de "uitkomst" de "res" variabele
        document.getElementById('uitkomst').value=res;  
    }

    // als je op de "C" button klik maakt hij de value "0"
    // en zorgt hij eigenlijk dat er niks in zit.
    function leeg(){
        document.getElementById('uitkomst').value="";
    }

</script>

<!-- Maak een gewone tabel aan en zorg voor de indeling van cijfers en andere knopjes.-->

The table for the calculator:
<table border="2" align="center">

    <tr>            
      <td colspan="3">
      <input style="background-color:black;color:white;" 
               type="text" name="uitkomst" id="uitkomst">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="+" onClick="nmr('+')" /> 
      </td>        
    </tr>

    <tr>        
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="1" onClick="nmr('1')" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="2" onClick="nmr('2')"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="3" onClick="nmr('3')"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="-"onClick="nmr('-')" />
      </td>        
    </tr>

    <tr>        
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="4" onClick="nmr('4')"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="5" onClick="nmr('5')"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="6" onClick="nmr('6')"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="X" onClick="nmr('*')"/> 
      </td>        
    </tr>

    <tr>        
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="7" onClick="nmr('7')"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="8" onClick="nmr('8')" /> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="9" onClick="nmr('9')" /> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="&divide;" onClick="nmr('/')" />
      </td>        
    </tr>

    <tr>   
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value=". " onClick="nmr('.')" /> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="0" onClick="nmr('0')" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="C" onClick="leeg()" /> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn1" value="=" onClick="reken()" /> 
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Did you share your all code ?

Comment: bind a single event listener to the document and watch for keypress / keyup events - use the returned `keyCode` value to determine if it is suitable as input to a calculator

Comment: @RishiRaut yes, the most.

Comment: @RamRaider I'm new at coding so I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Goks: As you are new, Please take a look at some examples. [Example 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwjNao),[Example 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNyYJM)

Answer (score 0):

To give you a potential starting point you might consider the following. The rudimentary calculator keypad below provides the basic buttons found on a typical calculator - each button on your keyboard has its own `keyCode` number assigned and you can access that number by inspecting the `event` object. These `events` are `keyup` and `click` in the below example - there are others but these will suffice here.

Each number button is assigned a name and a value - the name is not really required. Each `function` button is similarly assigned both name and value - in this instance you might make use of the name when performing your actual calculations as it might be easier to refer to the name rather than the value.

The javascript `event` listeners do nothing more than alert the value or keyCode but you will observe that no key when pressed will create that alert unless it is within the permitted range ( given by the array `validkeys` ) - this allows you to use both keyboard and mouse to act as input to your calculator. To add further `function` buttons inspect the console and whatever key you press should reveal the respective `keyCode` value.

```
<form id='calculator'>
   <div id='lhs'>
      <output></output>
      <section id='numpad'>
         <input type="button" name="k9" value="9" />
         <input type="button" name="k8" value="8" />
         <input type="button" name="k7" value="7" />
         <input type="button" name="k6" value="6" />
         <input type="button" name="k5" value="5" />
         <input type="button" name="k4" value="4" />
         <input type="button" name="k3" value="3" />
         <input type="button" name="k2" value="2" />
         <input type="button" name="k1" value="1" />
         <input type="button" name="k0" value="0" />
      </section>
   </div>
   <div id='rhs'>
      <section id='operations'>
         <input type="button" name="add" value="+" />
         <input type="button" name="subtract" value="-" />
         <input type="button" name="multiply" value="*" />
         <input type="button" name="divide" value="/" />
         <input type="button" name="point" value="." />
         <input type="button" name="equals" value="=" />
         <input type="button" name="clear" value="C" />
      </section>
   </div>
</form>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event){
        const output=document.querySelector('output');

        const keyhandler=function(e){
            let key=e.keyCode;
            console.info( key );
            /*
                permissable keys:
                integers 0-9

                0   =>  48
                1
                2
                3
                4
                5
                6
                7
                8
                9   =>  57

                c   =>  67
                +   =>  107
                -   =>  109
                *   =>  106
                /   =>  111
                =   =>  187
                .   =>  190

                numpad 0-9 
                96 - 105
            */
            const validkeys=[ 48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,67,107,109,106,111,187,190, 96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105 ];
            if( ~validkeys.indexOf( key ) ){
                /* Whatever key was pressed is in the permitted values */
                alert( key )
            }
        };
        const clickhandler=function(e){
            alert( this.value )
        };


        /* Bind event listeners - keyup and button click */
        document.addEventListener('keyup', keyhandler );

        Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]') ).forEach( bttn=>{
            bttn.addEventListener('click',clickhandler)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this may be an solution that works, it's clearly out of depth (bitwise operators, adding keyboard support) for what the OP was asking and there's no way he's going to make sense of what you are trying to do. I feel like you should have taken the OP's skill level into consideration.

Comment: @nbokmans - The `keyboard support` you mention was a specific requirement the @OP had so to omit that would be a poor start. It's true that on the surface this might appear complicated and perhaps outwith the ken of the OP ( perhaps we ought not judge that though! ) but as the they are attempting something of this level it is perhaps not too much of a step to take. I am so used to writing code like this I forget that others might not  be so familiar with some of the tricks involved ( the bitwise `~` etc )  but should they need or wish clarification that might further improve their learning.

Comment: How can I do when I press a key, it appears in the textbox. So if I click 2 at my keyboard, without clicking on the textbox the textbox will filled with "2" or if I click at '+' the textbox will filled with '+'

Comment: where the code does the `alert` is where you use that value.  Using the text input from your code, `document.getElementById('uitkomst').value=this.value` or `document.getElementById('uitkomst').value=e.key`

Comment: I knocked up a CodePen demo for you if you are interested.. https://codepen.io/RamRaider/pen/MWYoawR